# No matching function for call to sscanf

Tags: c++, scanf

Why am I getting this error with `sscanf`, having included `<cstdio>` and opened `file`?

I'm doing main:

```
string  line;
int     num = 0, i;
while(getline(file, line)){
    ++num;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &i) == 0) --num;
}
```

and getting error `No matching function for call to 'sscanf'`.

`sscanf` ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: @DevSolar Ah yes you're right. I hardly ever use these functions anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sscanf()` is a **C** function. The first parameter is expected to be of type `const char *`. You are passing it a **C++** `string`. As the types do not match, the compiler complains (as it should).

Try this:

```
sscanf( line.c_str(), "%d", &i )
```

Better yet, use [C++ I/O](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) which is much more robust:

```
file >> i
```

Comment: How does `file >> i` behave when not an int? Can I do `if (!(file >> i))` to test?

Comment: @OllieFord: I linked the reference page for `operator>>()`. You best work with the reference instead of what I say. But basically, `file >> i` evaluates to a reference to the input stream itself, which gets its `failbit` set when the conversion to `int` failed. So yes, your `if` should work (as a stream with `failbit` set evaluates to boolean `false`). You could also [configure the stream to throw an exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) for that case.

Comment: I'm getting the same error now on my own functions.. C++ seems not as transparent about what the issue is as C (in Xcode at least). Could it be because I'm passing the pointers wrong?

Comment: @OllieFord: Erm... one of the things that are making C++ I/O more robust is that it does not *use* any pointers?

Comment: No, it was the same error with other functions, no I/O. Just didn't want to ask another question. Fixed though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `sscanf(line.c_str()...`.

Answer (score 0):

[sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) is a C function, not a C++ function, and so it doesn't understand about the std::string class. Instead you need to pass in a pointer to a char array:

```
char buffer[32];
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &i);
```